# Recurrence relations of the form $T(n) = kT(n-1) + f(n)$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

What can be said about the asymptotic behaviour of recurrence relations of the form
$$
T(n) = kT(n-1) + f(n), \text{where } k \in \mathbb{N}^{\ge2}
$$
which often occur in recursive algorithm analysis?

It is well-known that $T(n) \in \Theta(k^n)$ when $f(n) \in O(n)$. But is there a result for general $f$? Or at least for polynomial $f(n) \in \Theta(n^P)$ or other standard classes of $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reccurence relation can be solved :

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N} $, and $ p\leq n $, we have : \begin{aligned}T\left(n-p\right)&=kT\left(n-p-1\right)+f\left(n-p\right)\\ \iff\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ k^{p}T\left(n-p\right)&=k^{p+1}T\left(n-p-1\right)+k^{p}f\left(n-p\right)\\ \Longrightarrow\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}{\left(k^{p}T\left(n-p\right)-k^{p+1}T\left(n-p-1\right)\right)}&=\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}{k^{p}f\left(n-p\right)}\\ \iff\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ T\left(n\right)-k^{n}T\left(0\right)&=\sum_{p=1}^{n}{k^{n-p}f\left(p\right)}\\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ T\left(n\right)&=k^{n}\left(T\left(0\right)+\sum_{p=1}^{n}{\frac{f\left(p\right)}{k^{p}}}\right)\end{aligned}

Thus, $ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right) $ : $$T\left(n\right)=k^{n}\left(T\left(0\right)+\sum_{p=1}^{n}{\frac{f\left(p\right)}{k^{p}}}\right)$$

Comment: Great answer! This implies that $T(n) \in \Theta(k^n)$ whenever $f(n) \in \Theta(n^P)$, right? And $T(n) \in \Theta(n \cdot k^n)$ when $f(n) = k^n$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You can transform the equation with

$$T(n)=k^nU(n),$$ giving

$$k^nU(n)=k^nU(n)+f(n)$$ or

$$U(n)=U(n-1)+k^{-n}f(n).$$

Then,

$$U(n)=U(0)+\sum_{i=1}^n k^{-i}f(i)$$ and $$T(n)=k^nT(0)+k^n\sum_{i=1}^n k^{-i}f(i)$$

Comment: Crossed with Chamsi.